# Scraping Google Front Page Results with php

Tags: php, screen-scraping

i can with php code Scraping title and url from google search results now how to get descriptions

```
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q=Beautiful+Bangladesh&oq=Beautiful+Bangladesh';
$html = file_get_html($url);

$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a');
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
    $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }

    echo '<p>Title: ' . $title . '<br />';
    echo 'Link: ' . $link . '</p>';
}
```

The above code gives the following output

```
Title: Natural Beauties - Bangladesh Photo Gallery
Link: http://www.photo.com.bd/Beauties/
```

Now I want the following output

```
Title: Natural Beauties - Bangladesh Photo Gallery
Link: http://www.photo.com.bd/Beauties/
description : photo.com.bd is a website for creative photographers from Bangladesh, mainly for amateur ... Natural-Beauty-of-Bangladesh_Flower · fishing on ... BEAUTY-4.
```

Comment: What is the HTML that you're parsing?  What attempt have you made to parse it?  In what way did that attempt not work as expected?

Comment: A file name doesn't answer any of those questions or provide any clarity to your question.  Currently you seem to be asking for somebody to do your work for you.  That's not really what Stack Overflow does.  If you're looking for somebody to add features to your code, you should hire a developer.  If *you* are trying to add features to your code and are stuck somewhere, we'll be happy to help.  But you need to describe the attempt you've made and the problem you've encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$in = "Beautiful Bangladesh";
$in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'';

print $url."<br>";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$i=0;
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a'); 
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
    $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }

    $descr = $html->find('span.st',$i); // description is not a child element of H3 thereforce we use a counter and recheck.
    $i++;   
    echo '<p>Title: ' . $title . '<br />';
    echo 'Link: ' . $link . '<br />';
    echo 'Description: ' . $descr . '</p>';
}
```