# Scraping search results using PHP and Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm working on making a web scraper where the goal is to allow a user to enter a search term, click a submit button, and receive a list of items related to their search.

Basically like a search engine would do, but instead of Google, I want the search to start from here: https://digitalcommons.colby.edu/special_collections/

The script below mostly works, but I'd like to have `$searchString` come from an input field on a form and then return the list of results after clicking the submit button. I'm currently using simple_html_dom.php.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
include_once('assets/inc/simple_html_dom.php');

$searchString = "Significant Inventions";
$in = $searchString;
$in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
$url  = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbo=d&site=&source=hp&q='.$in.'&oq='.$in.'';

echo '<h2>Title: ' . $searchString . '</h2>';
echo '<span>Title: ' . $url . '<span><hr>';

$html = file_get_html($url);

$i=0;
$linkObjs = $html->find('h3.r a'); 
foreach ($linkObjs as $linkObj) {
    $title = trim($linkObj->plaintext);
    $link  = trim($linkObj->href);

    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    }

    $descr = $html->find('span.st',$i); // description is not a child element of H3 thereforce we use a counter and recheck.
    $i++;   
    echo '<p>Title: ' . $title . '<br />';
    echo 'Link: <a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">Read More</a><br />';
    echo 'Description: ' . $descr . '</p><hr>';
}
?>
```

The above script is modified from [Scraping Google Front Page Results with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238146/scraping-google-front-page-results-with-php).

Comment: "I want to set a starting URL and turn it into a query string, which I can then scrape results from" - unclear question

Comment: Just updated the question - more specifically, I want to scrape the title, author, and link from each of the items returned on the results page.